# Replace NAs by a value which increment by 1 at each new NA

Tags: r

How can I replace NAs by a value which increments by 1 at each new NA which does not follow the previous value?

Here is an example:

```
ID
1
1
NA (replaced by 1)
NA (replaced by 1)
2
2
NA (replaced by 2)
NA (replaced by 2)
3
3
NA (replaced by 3)
NA (replaced by 3)
...
```

The expected result in this case is:

```
ID
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
...
```

**Data**

```
 df <- data.frame(ID=c( 1 , 1 , NA , NA , 2 , 2 , NA , NA , 3 , 3 , NA , NA ))
```

Comment: Is filling down with the last non-NA value sufficient? If so, the `na.locf` function from the `zoo` package does that.

Comment: In your example you're not incrementing by 1 for each NA, but for every two NAs. Just loop through the data, keep a count and replace NA with `(i %/% 2)` (or if you want what you describe just replace with the count i).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a remarkably quick and painless solution:

```
library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(ID=c( 1 , 1 , NA , NA , 2 , 2 , NA , NA , 3 , 3 , NA , NA ))
na.locf(df)
```

...should return

```
   ID
   1
   1
   1
   1
   2
   2
   2
   2
   3
   3
   3
   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
df <- c(1,1,NA,NA,2,2,NA,NA,3,3,NA,NA)

c(NA, df[!is.na(df)])[cumsum(!is.na(df)) + 1]
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```